# CodeIgniter seems to swallow (not log) PHP parse errors. Why?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is driving me nuts.

I install a clean copy of the latest CodeIgniter (3.1.9) in my Centos-Apache-PHP server (PHP 7.2.6).

Globally, my PHP logs errors to (say) `/var/www/logs/php_err.log`.

I check that indeed my PHP errors are logged there, including parse errors (`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)...`) , in any non-CI PHP page. It also logs if the parse error happens in a file included in by `require_once()`.

I also check that, inside CI application code (controller or model), it logs there when I call `error_log("something");`.

I even check that if I purposedly break CI's `index.php` (adding a `asd` line after the opening `<?php`, the parse error appears in my log.

The problem is that a parse error in (say) a controller (say, remove the first brace in `application/controllers/Welcome.php` ), gives a plain 500 error page, and **nothing in the log file**.

By changing the environment from `production`to `development` I can see the parse error in the web page. But still nothing in the logs. And, in any case, I definitely want the errors in the logs, also in production!

The problem persists if I comment out the whole "ERROR_REPORTING" block in `index.php`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Codeigniter uses its own error reporting system. To get errors to log, please take a look in the `config.php` file under `$config['log_threshold'];`. There is a definition table above the variable defining what different values equate to but I think `$config['log_threshold'] = 1;` will work for your purposes (by default it is 0 i.e. off). If you have different folders for production/development then you should modify this variable for both config files. By default, as shown in `index.php` production errors are suppressed from output via this line: `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`.

Logs will appear in `application/logs/` directory and are organized by `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the problem was not the default (it was 1, as it should) , but that my apache user had not write permissions on that dir. I feel that that should be mentioned in the installation docs... https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html

Comment: you always need write permissions for that kindof thing but yea, it should probably say "not writable" for such things to give a better understanding of what the error is.